# deeplink for .ics hosted file not opening in outlook mobile

Tags: email, hyperlink, download, html-email, icalendar

I have to generate an ics file and upload to AWS S3 and use the S3 url(https://xyz.s3.aws.com/invite.ics) in the email as a hyperlink to download the ics file. The hyperlink in the generated email is not working in outlook mobile app(saying - 'Unable to launch event'), whereas the hyperlink is working in desktop app. In desktop if I click on the hyperlink, it open the browser and download the ics file from the S3.

ical file content

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//sebbo.net//ical-generator//EN
NAME:my first iCal
X-WR-CALNAME:my first iCal
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:m8xj@gmail.com
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20200528T070711Z
DTSTART:20200527T191500Z
DTEND:20200528T070711Z
SUMMARY:Appoinment
LOCATION:7 Hills
DESCRIPTION:Calendar event test. Refer email for more details
ORGANIZER;CN="Team MCE":mailto:noreply@message.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Comment: Is the hyperlinked file publicly available? Perhaps you’re logged in on the desktop and thus the url can be accessed?

Comment: Its a public url. Also able to access the link in Gmail app and website

Comment: Just checking whether you googled the message and checked any of those suggestions? If you have, good idea to mention it so folks can see you have done your homework.EG: there are some suggestions here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918537/android-google-calendar-unable-to-launch-event

Comment: Yeah, I googled and none of the solutions resolved the issue. I attached the ical file for the reference

Comment: Manikandan.  These ics urls are supposed to be publicly accessible urls,  If you post the actual url, we can test it from our side for you.   The code you posted above is just the content and is missing the end of line characters.

Comment: Below is one of the ical I put it in s3 and it is public
https://mce-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/myevents.ics

Comment: This may be specific to your device. Have you tried another mobile device and / or the suggestions here re cache:  See https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/12829350?hl=en

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918537/android-google-calendar-unable-to-launch-event is the suggestion that the mobile app is less forgiving than web browser (?!)  One of the validators is not happy with the timezone info in that ics url.  See https://icalendar.org/validator.html?Itemid=?url=https://mce-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/myevents.ics

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the content-type to text/calendar as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-8.1 when uploading to S3 ?

Comment: Yeah, by default S3 set the content type to text/calendar. I verified that as well.